# Jquery Error :Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'html': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, razor

on my MVC3 razor page,I am trying to dynamically add a textbox with click of a button

Pasted below is my Jquery .But when I click addButton ,I am getting the above error message .

To resolve this error I tried adding  `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`  ,but still I am getting the same error .Appreciate your suggestions to resolve this error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function(){



        var counter = 2;



        $("#addButton").click(function () {



            if(counter>10){

                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");

                return false;

            }   



            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +

                '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 

                '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');



            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");



            counter++;

        });



        $("#removeButton").click(function () {

            if(counter==1){

                alert("No more textbox to remove");

                return false;

            }   

            counter--;



            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });



        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {



            var msg = '';

            for(i=1; i<counter; i++){

                msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();

            }

            alert(msg);

        });



  });

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What's with the empty `.after()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use jquery all the way instead of mixing up native DOM and jquery. this one will actually work:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div id="TextBoxDiv' + counter + '"><label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty obvious. If you call `after()` without any content, you are creating nothing. If you try to get the `html()` of nothing... you get nothing.

You might want to look at the `after()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/).